# Possible to run multiple squid containers on a single host?

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, containers, squid

I am trying to run multiple squid containers whose configs are built at container run time.  Each container needs to route traffic independently from the other.  Aside from where traffic is forwarded on, the configs are the same.

I can get a single squid container running and doing what I need it to with no problems.

```
docker run -v /var/log/squid:/var/log/squid -p 3133-3138:3133-3138 my_images/squid_test:version1.0
```

Trying to run a second container with:

```
docker run -v /var/log/squid:/var/log/squid -p 4133-4138:3133-3138 my_images/squid_test:version1.0
```

This instantly spits out: *Aborted (core dumped)*

I have one other container running on port 9000 but thats it.

This is a syslog dump from the host at the time the second container launch is attempted

```
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.356170] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered blocking state
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.356172] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered disabled state
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.356209] device veth89ab0c1 entered promiscuous mode
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.356252] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth89ab0c1: link is not ready
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-networkd[765]: veth89ab0c1: Link UP
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 networkd-dispatcher[1048]: WARNING:Unknown index 421 seen, reloading interface list
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[25899]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[25900]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[25899]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethb0dffb8: No such file or directory
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[25900]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth89ab0c1: No such file or directory
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 containerd[1119]: time="2020-06-18T04:45:17.567627817Z" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/85f0acae4a948ed16b3b29988291b5df3d052b10d1965f1198745966e63c3732/shim.sock" debug=false pid=25920
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.841905] eth0: renamed from vethb0dffb8
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.858172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth89ab0c1: link becomes ready
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.858263] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered blocking state
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84821.858265] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered forwarding state
Jun 18 04:45:17 dockerdevr1 systemd-networkd[765]: veth89ab0c1: Gained carrier
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-networkd[765]: veth89ab0c1: Gained IPv6LL
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 containerd[1119]: time="2020-06-18T04:45:19.221654620Z" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=85f0acae4a948ed16b3b29988291b5df3d052b10d1965f1198745966e63c3732
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 dockerd[1171]: time="2020-06-18T04:45:19.232623257Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-networkd[765]: veth89ab0c1: Lost carrier
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84823.251203] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered disabled state
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84823.254402] vethb0dffb8: renamed from eth0
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-networkd[765]: veth89ab0c1: Link DOWN
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84823.293507] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered disabled state
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84823.294577] device veth89ab0c1 left promiscuous mode
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 kernel: [84823.294580] docker0: port 3(veth89ab0c1) entered disabled state
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 networkd-dispatcher[1048]: WARNING:Unknown index 420 seen, reloading interface list
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 networkd-dispatcher[1048]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 420 seen even after reload
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[26041]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[26041]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for vethb0dffb8
Jun 18 04:45:19 dockerdevr1 systemd-udevd[26041]: Could not set offload features of vethb0dffb8: No such device
```

Has anyone tried something similar to this?  I know I can get multiple nginx containers running on different ports.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you get the docker logs?

Comment: I ran the container again simply just so I could get /bin/bash going and execute squid from within the container on my own.  I ran docker log during this time and it did not tell me anything other than the abort statement I mentioned above.  For clarification I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04. Surprisingly the dual squid container setup works on 16.04.  I am not sure what the difference is.